# Inserting DropDownList value in db

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am inserting selected value of drop downlist in db but it is giving me error in view where the dropdownlist helper is. There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'SpaceType'.
Model:

```
        public class AddSpace
        {
             public string SpaceType { get; set; }
        }
```

View:

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SpaceType,  (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["property"])
```

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddSpace()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Private Residence", Value = "Private Residence" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Office", Value = "Office" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Place of worship", Value = "Place of worship" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Commercial Parking lot", Value = "Commercial Parking lot" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Retail", Value = "Retail" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Academic Institution", Value = "Academic Institution" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Other", Value = "Other" });
        ViewData["property"] = items;
```

}

```
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult AddSpace(AddSpace adspace)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string userName = "wasfa_anjum@yahoo.com";
            var query = from q in Session.Query<Registration>()
                        where q.Email == userName
                        select q;
            Session.Store(adspace);
                Session.SaveChanges();


        }

        else ModelState.AddModelError("","Please Correct the errors to continue");
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [updated]:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SpaceTypes", ViewData["property"] as SelectList)
```

Also, after:

```
items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Other", Value = "Other" });
```

You'll probably need to add:

```
items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Other", Value = "Other" }, "Text", "Value", 1);
```

[added]
Optionally, you should be able to write it like this also:

```
var items = new SelectList(new[]
    new { Text = "Private Residence", Value = "Private Residence" },
    new { Text = "Office", Value = "Office" },
    new { Text = "Place of worship", Value = "Place of worship" },
    new { Text = "Commercial Parking lot", Value = "Commercial Parking lot" },
    new { Text = "Retail", Value = "Retail" },
    new { Text = "Academic Institution", Value = "Academic Institution" },
    new { Text = "Other", Value = "Other" },
"Text", "Value", 1);

ViewData["property"] = items;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast to a List:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SpaceType, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["property"])
```

Comment: still the same error There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SpaceType'.

Comment: What model is your view typed to? At the top, you should see `@model SomeModel`

Comment: View is typed to the model AddSpace..Am i missing something in HttpPost method??

Comment: Ah, you may need to repopulate the `ViewBag` in your `Post` action, the `ViewBag` is tied into your request's lifecycle.

Comment: Just do the same as you do in your `Get` action. Populate a list of `SelectListItems` and assign it to the ViewBag: `ViewData["property"] = items;`